# Domain not pointing ns after replaced ns

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, godaddy, domain-parking

I want add my domain in sedo parking.but before go with him I was park with afternic.after changed Name server 48+ hour's left the domain can't view with sedo .but the domain open in sedo office normally.after spend some day's with sedo .I left my domain with godaddy cashparking.same positions happened with me there .My domain shows with afternic.after replaced Name server with cashparking ns.her template is different for this services.after asking domain registrar and godaddy tech they your domain under website development mode and pointing ip address.how ? Just change ns and add dns records wait few hours and domains point ns.but not with me .so where is my domain stuck and how ? When I try to add my domain with godaddy then her system said your domain with Dan.otherwise I was deleted my domain with all places in Dan to [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIinc.jpg)

[This shows every time when I try add domain into godaddy](http://kittenfeed.online)

Comment: Your name servers are `ns1.dan.com` & `ns2.dan.com`. You can change them at the registrars service: https://www.name.com/account/login